# Authentication failure using Zoho smtp with Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to send email using my django app. But after setting Zoho account and adding necessary lines in settings.py I am still not able to send email and it keep giving **SMTPAuthenticationError (535, b'Authentication Failed')**.

```
#settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'administrator@technovate-iiitnr.org'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

#views.py
html =  render_to_string('email/code_email.html',{'code':code})
send_mail('Your Code',
'Hello',
'administrator@technovate-iiitnr.org',
['example@gmail.com'],
html_message=html
)
return render(request,'index.html')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason could be 2-factor authentication being used in the zoho account.
This prevents you from using account password, instead you need to generate application specific password and use the same.
Read more [here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/two-factor-authentication.html#alink5)